# Sequence Convergence when using a forgetting factor $\lambda$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd like to know how I can find the convergence formula of the following sequence

$x_{i} = \lambda x_{i-1} + y$ with $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $y$ a positive scalar and initially starting from $0$, so $x_{0}=0$. I was under the impression that asymptotically it would be equal to the value of $y$ but that only happens when $\lambda$ is the range of around $[0.9, 1)$ otherwise it's quite a bit lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recurrence has a simple solution
$$
x_{n}=\frac{y\left(\lambda^{n}-1\right)}{\lambda-1}.
$$
As $n\rightarrow\infty$, $\lambda^{n}\rightarrow0$, and hence
$$
x_{n}\rightarrow\frac{y}{1-\lambda}.
$$

--

Perhaps you meant the recurrence
$$
\tilde{x}_{n}=\lambda\tilde{x}_{n-1}+\left(1-\lambda\right)y
$$
(with $x_{0}=0$). This has solution
$$
\tilde{x}_{n}=y\left(1-\lambda^{n}\right)
$$
so that
$$\tilde{x}_n\rightarrow y.$$

Comment: how come in the first case that scalar $y$ is not even in the equation. Well to be more precise the sequence would be $x_{i} = \lambda x_{i} + y$ but in MatLab I would write it as in my initial post, I think.

Comment: That was a typo; that $k$ was meant to be a $y$. Fixed in the above. Also, the equal sign in MATLAB means "assignment," not "equality." It makes sense to write that in MATLAB, but most people reading mathematics would misinterpret (rightfully so) your equation $x_i=\lambda x_i+ y$ as $x_i=\frac{y}{\left(1-\lambda\right)}$. That is to say, your recurrence equation in the original post was the correct way of doing things.

Comment: right @par, thanks for the insightful answer... as a side note: too many years of computer science and my notations have been corrupted! Also if you have time, could you expand on how that formula $x_{n}$ is calculated?